# Get a file name from string output using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have output as string out of which I need to parse a specific file name:

```
>>> a = "Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser privileges or access to your account. [1] 15:04:16 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.1 abc330b125.tar.bz2 my-libs.tar.bz2 xyz-notok-0.tar.gz Stderr: Could not create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.ssh'. Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/usr/share/httpd/.ssh/known_hosts)."
```

I tried this, but instead of getting `abc330b125.tar.bz2`, I am getting `bs.tar.bz2`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*([abc|xyz\-ok|!my].*.tar.bz2)', a)
['bs.tar.bz2']
```

Can someone please let me know if I am making any mistake here?

Comment: Square brackets create character sets that will match only one of the characters contained within them. The pattern `[abc|xyz\-ok|!my]` matches a, b, c, k, m, o, x, y, z, -, !, or | exactly once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using "findall," so I assume you want to find all of the tar files. If that's the case, this will work:

```
re.findall('\S*\.tar\.bz2', a)

['abc330b125.tar.bz2', 'my-libs.tar.bz2']
```

If you only want to find the ones beginning with "abc," containing only letters and numbers, you could use this:

```
re.findall('abc\w*\.tar\.bz2', a)

['abc330b125.tar.bz2']
```

Comment: It will have only one file which I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Sweety Note that `[\w\d]` = `\w`, you may "simplify" the pattern a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:abc.*\d+.tar.bz2|xyz\-ok.*.tar.bz2)', a)
['abc330b125.tar.bz2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
re.findall(r"[\w-]+\.tar.bz2",a)
```

## result

```
# ['abc330b125.tar.bz2', 'my-libs.tar.bz2']
```

If you want all filenames, you can do it:

```
re.findall(r"[\w-]+\.tar.(bz2|gz)",a)
```

## result

```
# ['abc330b125.tar.bz2', 'my-libs.tar.bz2', 'xyz-notok-0.tar.gz' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use regex101.com (awesome website for testing regular expressions) to make some tests and it seems that this regular expression :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*(.)(tar)(.)(bz2)
```

captures what you are asking for.

I'm sure you already know, but for anyone who might want a clarification: to capture the actual "." in the string, you need to enclose them in parentheses.

Hope this helps !

Comment: `(.)` is the same as `.`, except it creates a capturing group. `[.]` will match a literal `.`, as will `\.`.

Comment: Oups, my bad. How would you fix my answer to make it more relevant ?